# table specific privileges

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, database-administration

I want to implement privileges in phpmyadmin, at table level. I want certain columns only to be shown to the user.

Here is the query I used.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON `resource_test`.`resources` FROM 'test_user'@'%';

GRANT SELECT (`resource_id`, `first_name`) ON `resource_test`.`resources` TO 'test_user'@'%'WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But I am unable to select only selected fields/columns.

Is it possible to only show the user a few number of columns only?

For your information i m using MySQL - 5.1.50

Comment: I get an error for viewing the tables saying "select command denied to the user on table". If I choose, only table specific privileges.

Answer (score 0):

ya it is possible.

```
GRANT SELECT (columnname) ON person TO SomeOne
```

Refer [DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Answer (score 0):

yes

```
GRANT select(col1, col2,...) On tbl To user
```

something like

```
 GRANT select (id,name) ON Users To scott
```

where id and name are cols in table Users

Comment: It returns me usage i.e no privileges are assigned in this case. I need to select all the columns in the table for this to work. Or else the select operator  or privilege is not given

Comment: @SeemaSharma check columns_priviles table under information_schema database .. if you can find the corresponding entrt there .. then its working

Comment: Ya, In column privileges table, there is an entry for the selected fields, but in the user privileges table the values for the below mentioned fields are as follows: privilege_type is usage and table_catalog is Null. I believe this could be the problem for select not working as expected.

Comment: @SeemaSharma what is the result if run run the select query with the user to which you have assigned the privilege..?

Comment: I could execute the grant query successfully but if I login to access the tables for the chosen user, then on accessing the table I get the following error saying, "SELECT command denied to user X on On accessing the table for table resources"